# How to compare string in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

In interview I got question to sort the array first in LNAME and then FNAME **without using any in-built function**  like(`compare`, `compareTo`, `Collections.sort`).

```
String NAMES[][]={{"Abse","Blase"},{"Gua","Tysg"},{"Hysdt","Tyser"}};
```

Unfortunately, I compared the String like below

```
    String fname;
    String lname;
    for (int i = 0; i < NAMES.length; i++) {
        lname = NAMES[i][0];
        for (int j = i + 1; j < NAMES.length; j++) {
            if (NAMES[j][1] < lname) {  // showing compilation error :(

            }
        }
    }
```

And, I came to know that, It was wrong. Then, how can I compare them  without using any in-built function ?

Note: I haven't added full snippet. Just wanted to know, how can we compare String.

Comment: What do you mean by "without using any in-built function"? No method calls? I don't think there's any way to access the characters in a String without using methods on it.

Comment: you are looking for `String.compareTo()`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name No, They mentioned shouldn't use that

Comment: [String.compareTo()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo-java.lang.String-)

Comment: If you do not want to use compareTo(), you have to write your own method.

Comment: @jWeaver: then you need to implement `compareTo()` yourself. But requesting "*no built-in method **at all***" is stupid. Because there is no way you can access the contents of the strings without using an built-in method. You should be glad you don't have to work for them.

Comment: *without using any in-built function* did you mean only functions which directly compares string and not the ones like lowercase(), length(), charAt()?

Answer (score 2):

According to the String.class compareTo(String s) method states the following. You can probably refer the below snippet but again it will not fulfil your requirement as the compareTo method uses Math function. But I believe this is what the interviewer was looking for.

```
  public int compareTo(String s)
{
    int i = value.length;
    int j = s.value.length;
    int k = Math.min(i, j);
    char ac[] = value;
    char ac1[] = s.value;
    for(int l = 0; l < k; l++)
    {
        char c = ac[l];
        char c1 = ac1[l];
        if(c != c1)
            return c - c1;
    }

    return i - j;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty hard inteview question. It's more like a school assignment ;)

```
   public void sort() {

        String NAMES[][] = {{"Abse", "Blase"}, {"Gua", "Blase"}, {"Gua", "Tysg"}, {"Hysdt", "Tyser"}};
        List<String[]> result = new ArrayList<>(3);

        for (String[] name : NAMES) {
            if (result.isEmpty()) {
                result.add(name);
                continue;
            }
            int addAt = 0;
            for (String[] sortedName : result) {
                if (isBefore(name, sortedName)) {
                    break;
                }
                addAt++;
            }
            result.add(addAt, name);
        }

    }

    private boolean isBefore(String[] name, String[] name2) {
        //last name
        int position = 0;

        char[] lastName1 = name[1].toLowerCase().toCharArray();
        char[] lastName2 = name2[1].toLowerCase().toCharArray();
        while (lastName1.length > position && lastName2.length > position) {
            if (lastName1[position] < lastName2[position]) {
                return true;
            } else if (lastName1[position] > lastName2[position]) {
                return false;
            }
            position++;
        }


        position = 0;
        char[] firstName1 = name[0].toLowerCase().toCharArray();
        char[] firstName2 = name2[0].toLowerCase().toCharArray();
        while (firstName1.length > position && firstName2.length > position) {
            if (firstName1[position] < firstName2[position]) {
                return true;
            } else if (firstName1[position] > firstName2[position]) {
                return false;
            }
            position++;
        }

        //equal so whatever
        return false;
    }
```

I have a feeling you would be able to do this with lambdas *a lot* easier, but I don't really know

Answer (score 0):

> `<` or `>` operator cannot compare `Strings`, so we can use it to compare characters.

Maybe implement your own string comparision method. Which checks character by character and returns the String with the highest value.

```
public String compare(String s1, String s2)
{
   for(int i = 0; i < Math.min(s1.length(), s2.length()); i++)
   {
        if(s1.charAt(i) > s2.charAt(i))
          return s1;
   }
     return s2;
}
```

To complete the answer to your question.

```
    public class GreatString {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String NAMES[][] = { { "Abse", "Blase" }, { "Gua", "Tysg" },
                { "Hysdt", "Tyser" } };
        int n = NAMES.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = i; j < n; j++) {
                if (NAMES[i][0].equals(NAMES[j][0])) {
                    if (compare(NAMES[i][1], NAMES[j][1])) {
                        String[] temp = NAMES[i];
                        NAMES[i] = NAMES[j];
                        NAMES[j] = temp;
                    } else {
                        if (compare(NAMES[i][0], NAMES[j][0])) {
                            String[] temp = NAMES[i];
                            NAMES[i] = NAMES[j];
                            NAMES[j] = temp;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < NAMES[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.println(NAMES[i][j]);}}
    }

    private static boolean compare(String str1, String str2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int len = str1.length() < str2.length() ? str1.length() : str2.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (str1.charAt(i) > str2.charAt(i))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```